# How to import zip file into visual studio code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have a whole flutter project and want to import in visual studio code, but the file is in zip file.How to import whole zip file into visual studio code.

Comment: unzip and open..

Comment: Did you try this? 
 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-zipexplorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Unzip your file in a new folder (let's say **my_awesome_project**)
2. Open VS Code and choose "Open Folder"
3. It's done

Make sure you have the Flutter extension installed in VS Code to enjoy your coding time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new folder on your Desktop.
2. Right-click on the zip file and click on the option **"**Extract file with a specified folder.****
3. Select the Folder that you just made.
4. Open that folder with VS-Code.
5. Done. Enjoy Your Day:)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to unzip your files and then open that folder in vs code.